# Category tree from specific parent category

Tags: php, magento

With the code below I try to get the children categories from a specific parent category with ID 7.

```
<?php
    $rootCatId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

    function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild){
        $allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId));

        $class = ($isChild) ? "sub-cat-list" : "cat-list";
        $html .= '<ul class="'.$class.'">';
        foreach($allCats as $category)
        {
            $html .= '<li>'.$category->getName()."";
            $subcats = $category->getChildren();
            if($subcats != ''){
                $html .= getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }
    $catlistHtml = getTreeCategories($rootCatId, false);

    echo $catlistHtml;

?>
```

With this code all categories shown. How I can get this tree only from the specific category with ID 7?

Michael

Comment: ask at http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.I hope that you get result.

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(7);
foreach ($children as $category) {
    echo $category->getName();
}
```

More help is [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33329/)

Comment: Have you get result using this @Michael van Eijden